# How to programmatically set an initial state for an Eclipse UI command?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I am extending `org.eclipse.ui.commands` to provide a new command to my `menuContribution` which has a `toggle` style.

Now I want to set an initial state, but it should not be a hard-coded state. Consequently, providing the following state is not an option:

```
  <state
         class="org.eclipse.ui.handlers.RegistryToggleState:true"
         id="org.eclipse.ui.commands.toggleState">
   </state>
```

The state should reflect a property in the preference page, there's no need to persist anything. Setting the state manually by invoking the methods in the plugin `Activator` does not work, because I will jump into the `start` method as soon as I click on the command for the first time, but that's too late since the context menu should already reflect the correct state of the preference property.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should implement your own State class which shall extend `org.eclipse.jface.commands.ToggleState` and override `setState` method. It can take any value, but ignore it and do what you want (read preferences etc.)

I have not tried to do it, just guessing.

Comment: I tried this already, but the problem is that my implementation (`setState`) won't be invoked.

Comment: Apparently the ID of the state must be `org.eclipse.ui.commands.toggleState`. I supplied my custom ID and I guess that's why my code was never invoked.

Comment: Oh, `ToggleState` has `setValue` method, not `setState`. I'm just confused )

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. Can you confirm that it is supposed to work by not using a custom identifier but `org.eclipse.ui.commands.toggleState`?

Comment: I don't know. Just found that in our code we set toggle button's state directly from its handler (`setInitializationData` method). It does the similar job that yours and stores value in `PlatformUI.getPreferenceStore()`, The state has a custom id and it is used to get current state of the command (`command.getState(id)`) in `execute` and set a new value. Don't sure it was necessary.